# MySQL Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, alter-table

I have two tables created in MySQL. Their create query are as below

```
CREATE TABLE ix_consultant_affected_columns (
  master_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  logging_session int(10) NOT NULL,
  text_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  table_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  column_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (text_id, master_id, logging_session, table_id, column_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT charset = latin1;

CREATE TABLE ix_consultant_query_text (
  master_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  logging_session int(10) NOT NULL,
  text_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  count int(10) NOT NULL,
  discarded tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  query_type varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  no_tuner_score float DEFAULT NULL,
  num_rows_affected float DEFAULT NULL,
  text_plan longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (logging_session, master_id, text_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT charset = latin1;
```

Now I want to apply foreign key in alter query. But it gives 
**Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint**

The alter query is :

```
ALTER TABLE ix_consultant_affected_columns
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES ix_consultant_query_text (master_id),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (logging_session) REFERENCES ix_consultant_query_text (logging_session),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (text_id) REFERENCES ix_consultant_query_text (text_id);
```

I tried looking for constraints or datatype differences between two. But I'm not able to identify the issue. 
**NOTE:** If I run alter query using only logging_session column the query works fine and foreign key is applied. The issue is with master_id and text_id

**EDIT:**

I found the issue is that the alter query isn't in the sequence of the referenced table. The primary index sequnce in ix_consultant_query_text table is :

1. logging_session
2. master_id
3. text_id

So when I created the alter query in the referenced table's primary index sequence it worked fine.

```
ALTER TABLE ix_consultant_affected_columns 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (logging_session,master_id,text_id) REFERENCES ix_consultant_query_text(logging_session,master_id,text_id)
```

The issue now is that I'm creating this alter query dynamically, So is there a way to get the sequence of the columns (primary index) from referenced table?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add three foreign keys to next fields in `ix_consultant_query_text` table:

- `text_id`
- `master_id`
- `logging_session`

But only `ix_consultant_query_text`.`logging_session` is unique.
Foreign key creation requires all referenced fields to be unique.

Comment: Primary key is applied to text_id, master_id and logging_session in ix_consultant_query_text. So how is logging_session only unique? 
Also what could be the solution for this?

Comment: The primary key is complex, it contains several fields: `logging_session`, `master_id`, `text_id`. We can say that all these fields forms unique group. And we can say than only the first field is also unique. All other, are not unique.

Comment: Do you need to create three foreign keys? Or, possible, it is needed to create one complex foreign key with three related fields? I think you should tell more about database schema you need.

Comment: I can even create one complex foreign key. Using manual query I found a solution but I don't know how to get the primary index sequence of a table. Please check updated question

Comment: You can get a list of indexes/foreign keys columns from the information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE system table. But, I do not think it is a good idea to create keys dynamically every time. It's better to think about database schema logic to make database stable, and not change it every time.

Comment: I'm migrating the database from sybase to MySql. That's why I need to apply foreign key dynamically

Comment: If it is possible to create DDL (all CREATE TABLE statements) from sybase, then try to rewrite it to MySQL syntax, and run the script using `foreign_key_checks` system variable - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks. Set it to 0 before the script, it will help to recreate all foreign keys without dependency notifications.

Comment: So would it not generate an issue if a reference is made to a column of the table which hasn't been created yet?

Comment: foreign_key_checks will force MySQL to create invalid foreign keys, even when there is no referenced table.